# Filter product title for Woocommerce Order Items

Tags: woocommerce, filter

I want wo add custom attribute for each product name in woocommerce order. Here is my code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_get_items', 'filter_woocommerce_order_get_items', 10, 2 );
function filter_woocommerce_order_get_items($items, $instance){
    foreach ($items as $item_id => $item){
        $id = $item['product_id'];
        $brand = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $id, 'pa_brand', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
        if($brand) {
            $items[$item_id]['name'] = $item['name'] . ' [' . $brand . ']';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

It looks normal for an old orders. But if it is a new order I've got such result:

[image]

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

Add Custom Attributes to Individual Products
Sometimes it is important to add any custom attributes for an unique products as needed rather than going through the above-described procedure of setting pre-configured attributes. When you have different products with different attributes then you need to add custom attribute for individual products.

- Go to WordPress dashboard
- Select the specific products
- Scroll down to the Product Data section and find attributes option
- Click Attributes. The drop down menu for “Custom product attribute” is already selected. Click Add.
- Name your attributes and add values
- Save attributes
  For better understanding you can follow this [tutorial](https://pixelaar.com/how-to-add-and-manage-products-attributes-in-woocommerce/)